Let $\Omega$ be the region in the first quadrant, enclosed by $y = 0$, $y = 3x$ and $y = -x^2 + 4$. Find the volume of the solid generated...
Could you help me to see if my analysis is good or wrong?
Let $\Omega$ be the region in the first quadrant, enclosed by $y = 0$, $y = 3x$ and $y = -x^2 + 4$. Find the volume of the solid generated by revolving $\Omega$ about $y$-axis.
This is what I graph for $\Omega$.

After revolving $\Omega$ about $y$-axis, I have this:

I'm using the washer method to calculate the volume. I solve each equation $y = 3x$ and $y = -x^2 + 4$ for $x$. I got $x=\frac{y}{3}$ and $x=\sqrt{4-y}$. Then I applied the formula for the volume using the washer method where the outter radius is $x=\sqrt{4-y}$ and the inner radius is $x=\frac{y}{3}$. The limits of integration are $y$ values. The integral I'm doing is
$V=\pi\int_{0}^{3} [(\sqrt{4-y})^{2}-(\frac{y}{3})^{2}] \,dy $
The result I'm getting is $\frac{13\pi}{2}$ cubic units.
Is my analysis ok?
Thanks in advance.

can you please shade the volume of the figure we have to find? is it the middle white conical region?

@Mathslover I already did. There are two pictures. The second one is the solid of revolution form by rotating $\Omega$ by the $y$-axis. Aren't the two pictures showing?

The setup looks fine. You can double check it by seeing if the shell method gives the same answer.
